# Почему некорректно работает скрипт?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Для фиксации блоков использую скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $nav = $('.header_box');
    $nav2 = $('.content_box_fixed');
    $window = $(window);
    $h = $nav.offset().top;
    $h2 = $nav.offset().top;
    $window.scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > 800) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > $h) {
            $nav.addClass('header_box_fixed');
        } else {
            $nav.removeClass('header_box_fixed');
        }
    }
    if ($(this).width() > 800) {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > $h2) {
            $nav2.addClass('content_box_fixed_active');
        } else {
            $nav2.removeClass('content_box_fixed_active');
        }
    }
    });
});
```

Здесь пример не публикую, потому что здесь работает четко. На сайте же во время прокрутки страницы, скрипт срабатывает с каким-то дерганьем, а именно общий контейнер "подскакивает" во время срабатывания скрипта. Не могу понять почему. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, где ошибка? Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не скажу по конкретному примеру, но в практике такое встречаю. Причина чаще всего такая - между двумя блоками (блоком, который становится fixed при скроле и блок под ним/над ним) есть либо **`padding`** либо **`margin`**. Когда элемент получает свойство fixed, разница этих **`padding`** либо **`margin`** не учитывается и происходит скачёк елемента на высоту, равную **`padding`** либо **`margin`**. Проверяйте.

**UPD:**

Конкретно по вашему примеру - когда **`.header`** получает **`fixed`**, следующий за ним **`.conteiner`** поднимается до упора вверх. Поэтому он должен получать **`margin-top:30px`** (это высота .header) что бы компенсировать потерю упора от **`.header`**.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $nav = $('.header_box');
    $nav2 = $('.content_box_fixed');
    $window = $(window);
    $h = $nav.offset().top;
    $h2 = $nav.offset().top;
    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).width() > 800) {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > $h) {
                $nav.addClass('header_box_fixed');
            } else {
                $nav.removeClass('header_box_fixed');
            }

            if ($window.scrollTop() > $h2) {
      /* --> */ $nav2.addClass('content_box_fixed_active').css('padding-top', $nav.height() + 'px'); // тут
            } else {
      /* --> */ $nav2.removeClass('content_box_fixed_active').css('padding-top', 'initial'); // тут
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @LADYX обновил в ответе.

Comment: Создайте пример, будем посмотреть. Я по ссылке проверил - когда хедер клеится к топу, контейнер под ним подскакивает под него. маржин решает).

Comment: @LADYX обновил в ответе.

Comment: хз... скорее всего совместимось.  Попробуйте вместо margin-top поставить padding-top. Либо прописать дополнительно маржин с вендорным префиксом -webkit-margin-top.